# ignoring calculated fields in deserialization

Tags: java, json, jackson, pojo

i have a class:

```
class MyClass {
  @Getter
  @Setter
  int a;

  @Getter
  @Setter
  int b;

  public int getADivB() {
    return a / b;
  }
}
```

when serializing i need all three properties to be serialized. however if another java process is deserializing the message i would like jackson to ignore the calculated field. (not ignore it all together as with @JSONIgnore)

deserialization code is:

```
String json = ... //get json from message
JsonNode root = this.mapper.readTree(json);
MyClass abdiv = this.mapper.readValue(root, MyClass.class);
```

Comment: I only see two fields, where is the third?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need is to annotate calculated property with `@JsonProperty`
so it will look like this:

```
class MyClass {
  @Getter
  @Setter
  int a;

  @Getter
  @Setter
  int b;

  @JsonProperty
  public int getADivB() {
    return a / b;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can annotate your class with

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
```

to have the property ignored by Jackson during deserialization.

Answer (score 0):

serialization will not serialize the a/b in the method, only the member fields